# How to create multi-page app in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to create a multi-page program in which there will be 4 topics for users to select from. When user clicks on any particular topic it will display that particular topic page content. Each topic will contain 2-3 pages with next previous button. User can select one or multiple topics. And when all selected topics are viewed, user will be redirected back to topic selection page with already viewed topics greyed out. I had previously created such kind of program using jQuery however, I'm having hard time figuring out to do in react's way. The URL will stay fixed. The main issue i'm facing here is show/hidding components on click event which is nested 2-3 levels inside. I tried using props but it seems to only work with parent-child relationship.

```
var topicsPage = [
    { 
        topic_no: '1',
        topic_page_no: '1',
        headline: 'Topic 1 headline', 
        description: 'Topic 1 description comes here...', 
        first_topic_page: true,
        last_topic_page: false
    },
    { 
        topic_no: '2',
        topic_page_no: '2',
        headline: 'Topic 2 headline', 
        description: 'Topic 2 description comes here...', 
        first_topic_page: false,
        last_topic_page: false
    },
    { 
        topic_no: '3',
        topic_page_no: '3',
        headline: 'Topic 3 headline', 
        description: 'Topic 3 description comes here...', 
        first_topic_page: false,
        last_topic_page: false
    },
    { 
        topic_no: '4',
        topic_page_no: '4',
        headline: 'Topic 4 headline', 
        description: 'Topic 4 description comes here...', 
        first_topic_page: false,
        last_topic_page: true
    }
];

var MainContainer = React.createClass({

    render: function() {    
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <TopicsList />
                <SelectedTopicPage />
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var TopicsList = React.createClass({

    onClick: function () {

    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="row topic-list">
                <SingleTopicBox 
                    topicID="1" 
                    onClick={this.onClick} 
                    label="Topic"
                    />
                <SingleTopicBox 
                    topicID="2" 
                    onClick={this.onClick} 
                    label="Topic"
                    />
                <SingleTopicBox 
                    topicID="3" 
                    onClick={this.onClick} 
                    label="Topic"
                    />
                <SingleTopicBox 
                    topicID="4" 
                    onClick={this.onClick} 
                    label="Topic"
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var SingleTopicBox = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-sm-2">
                    <div onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(null, this)} className="single-topic" data-topic-id={this.props.topicID}>
                        {this.props.label} {this.props.topicID}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});



var SelectedTopicPage = React.createClass({

    render: function() {    
        return (
            <div className="topics-page">
                <h1>{this.props.headline}</h1>
                <p>{this.props.description}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


ReactDOM.render(<MainContainer />, document.getElementById('main-container'));
```

Comment: React is just a library to render DOM elements. So it really does not care of how many pages your app has.

Comment: @zerkms Is there a more efficient way to handle multiple pages instead of having to show/hide them like in other mvc frameworks such as Ruby on Rails.

Comment: React is not a framework, it's a library. Its purpose is to render elements, it does not care how you use it.

Comment: @RahulDagli Yes, there is a more efficient way: don't render them. Within your render function, you can conditionally render the components you want and not the ones you don't. The un-rendered components will never appear in the DOM - in fact, they'll never be processed at all. You could also use `react-router` with [`createMemoryHistory`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#creatememoryhistory), which will not change the address bar. As mentioned, React is for the DOM, so you still need a business layer. Check out Flux or Redux.